# How do I update a table in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I have a table in database 1 with columns x and y. I have another table in database 2 with columns x and y. I want to update all the y columns in database 1 to the y columns in database 2 where the x columns in database 1 match the x columns in database 2.

This seems like an unbelievably trivial task, but I can't figure out how to do it in SSIS. I have an OLE DB Source and Destination in my data flow task and I have the 2 columns mapped, but it keeps trying to insert instead of update, and it fails because there are a bunch of other non-nullable columns in the destination that I don't have mapped.

Comment: How many rows are there in each table? Ball park.

Comment: In the table to be updated, there are millions of rows. In the source table, there are just a few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with using SSIS to do data transformation is that both the source and target data sets need to be pulled up into memory on the ETL server, the transformation needs to happen there, and then the results have to be written back down to the destination server.

It's network intensive. It's memory intensive. It's just less than ideal. That's also why you're having trouble figuring it out. On a server, it's just an `UPDATE` statement, but getting it up into SSIS requires many more steps than just that, and absent third party tools, there's no out of the box method to do anything other than row by row updates.

In your situation, where your source data is comparatively lightweight, I would suggest that the most efficient approach would be to use SSIS to move the source data from the source server to the target server and drop it into a working/holding/intermediate table. SSIS is absolutely awesome at moving data from point A to point B. Then, after the `Data Flow`, use an `Execute SQL` task to either call an `UPDATE` stored procedure, or go ahead and write the `UPDATE` statement in the package.

Doing it that way off-loads the DML from the ETL server to the SQL Server, which is designed for exactly that kind of work. Sort of a "let everybody do what they're good at" approach, if you will.

Answer (score 0):

OK so rather than trying to directly map the data from DB2 into DB1, it's probably a better idea to stage the data from DB2 into DB1 and then update the table of interest in DB1.

The best way to do this is to create a new table in DB1 that stores all of the data from the table in DB2. Let's call this table 'staging'. Use SSIS to do a flat insert from the table in DB2 to your new 'staging' table in DB1 and then create an UPDATE stored procedure in your DB1 database to update existing entries in your endpoint table based on the entries you now have in your 'staging' table. You can trigger the SP from SSIS to run after your staging table is populated. You can cut out the 'staging' table here if you have a synonym from DB1 that references the table in DB2.

SSIS is more about bulk movement of data than it is updating what already exists. Use stored procedures for anything in between.